# Devise edit user not working after using custom registrations controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

it might be a silly question but I am stuck with this for some time as I am new to rails.
I am basically using a custom registration controller to overwrite devise

```
class RegistrationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /Users
  def index
    @Users = User.all
  end

  # GET /Users/1
  def show
  end

  # GET /Users/new
  def new
    @User = User.new
    @course = Course.find_by id: params["course_id"]
  end

  # POST /Users
  def create
    @User = User.new(user_params)
    if @User.save
      redirect_to @User.paypal_url(registration_path(@User))
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  protect_from_forgery except: [:hook]
  def hook
    params.permit! # Permit all Paypal input params
    status = params[:payment_status]
    if status == "Completed"
      @User = User.find params[:invoice]
      @User.update_attributes notification_params: params, status: status, transaction_id: params[:txn_id], purchased_at: Time.now
    end
    render nothing: true
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @User = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:course_id, :name, :email, :password,:password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

In my routes I have

```
devise_for :users ,:controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }
```

So now I have

```
edit_user_registration_path GET /users/edit(.:format)   registrations#edit
```

My question is how can I route only **edit** back to devise/registrations/edit or what can i add to my registrations controller so that I get something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delegate the create action of the registrations controller to Devise, I recommend you to create a controller that inherits from the Devise one:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    super #We call super because we don't want to override this action
  end
  def edit
    #Custom code to override this action
  end
end
```

Your route's configuration stays as it is, you just have to change your controller, you may also want to know that it's possible to ADD functionality to what devise already does, instead of override it:

```
def edit
  super do |resource|
    #Here you add what you'll do AFTER devise works
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helped me think on how I can do it.